# Angular - close modal window with event

Tags: angular

I would like to fire an event when the close button is clicked within the modal window.
The button has the attribute `data-dismiss="modal"` and doesn't call the `click` event. Is it possible to have data-dismiss and `click` event or only `click` event and close modal from class?

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="close()">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalHeader}}</h4>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


close() {
    //Can I close modal window manually?
    this.onClose.emit();
  }
```

Method `close` dont call because button has `data-dismiss` attribute.

Thank you

Comment: Using jQuery use can close the model.

Comment: @Sreemat this is an Angular question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In angular, use `[hidden]` attribute to show/hide the model popup,  and remove `data-dismiss="modal"` in your close button

try this

```
<div [hidden]="IsmodelShow" class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalHeader}}</h4>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div  

close() {
    this.IsmodelShow=true;// set false while you need open your model popup
   // do your more code
}
```

---

## Update

just add `data-target="#modal"` in your div and it will be works

```
<div class="modal-dialog" data-target="#modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="close()">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalHeader}}</h4>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


close() {
//write your code
}
```

Update 2

> You need to set data-target as target id of your modal and data-toggle = "modal" to the button on which you want to activate the modal

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-target="#myupdate" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Update</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myupdate" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">New Update </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a small modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="close()">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: how will this work, if i click outside the modal to close it?

Comment: @reverie_ss see the 2nd updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your `close` function add this

```
close() {
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line on top before `@Component` starts.

```
declare var $: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the `data-dismiss="modal"` and call a function, instead inside your close function do the following:

```
close() {
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
}
```

I'm assuming you're using bootstrap, so you're using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, but It not works. I have this modal: `<div class="modal"><div class="modal-dialog" id="modal"></div></div>` and when I use `$('#modal').modal('hide');`, error is __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery___default(...)(...).modal is not a function

Answer (score 0):

data-dismiss property is important.
I just use it and got the success.

if you want to perform any additional operation on closing then handle the onClick event as below